# X-ray diffraction analyisis: The angle of elastic x-ray scattering

Tags: scattering, probability, x-ray-crystallography

What is the scattering angle distribution for x-rays (in the 8keV range) scattered elastically?

I work with XRD analysis, which is fundamentally basede on these elastic scatterings of x-rays. I read somewhere that the scattering angle is most often very similar to the original trajectory, i.e. very small. However, routine analysis involves measuring scattering at 90 degrees. But how probable is this?

It is well known that acquired data is poorer for large angles, and this is compensated for by allowing more photons to hit the sample (by using a so-called adjustable divergence slit). If this is simply to compensate for the low probability of elastic scattering of these large angles, then my understanding just improved greatly!

Anyone here who can confirm this, or shed new light on the matter?

Answer (score 1):

The ratio between reflected and incident intensities, i.e. reflectivity is an important factor at small angles, but still to always satisfy Bragg condition, you have to use continuum X-rays. If you use monochromatic X-rays then Bragg is achieved at a specific angle only.